# Parameterized query not generating correct FillMethod

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I have a table that I create a custom query for with the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard (VS2010). The query is:

```
SELECT AssociateName, TimeField, InOut, Reason, [Key] FROM PunchEventTable
WHERE  (TimeField =
                   (SELECT  MAX(TimeField) AS Expr1
                    FROM     PunchEventTable PunchEventTable_1
                    WHERE  (AssociateName LIKE ?))) AND (AssociateName LIKE ?)
```

The code it generates is:

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
 Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0"),  _
 Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter"),  _
 Global.System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Fill, false)>  _
Public Overloads Overridable Function FillByLast(ByVal dataTable As TTDataSet.PunchEventTableDataTable, ByVal AssociateName As String) As Integer
    Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(2)
    If (AssociateName Is Nothing) Then
        Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
    Else
        Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = CType(AssociateName,String)
    End If
    If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = true) Then
        dataTable.Clear
    End If
    Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

but I've found that this doesn't work because each '?' in the query is treated as a separate parameter, so what I really need are the additional lines:

```
Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter)
Me.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters(1).Value = CType(AssociateName, String)
```

to set the second '?' to the AssociateName as well. As indicated at the top of the Designer.vb file, this file is auto-generated, so my changes do not always persist (and therefore doing this manually sounds like a terrible idea). Can anyone suggest how to make it generate this code appropriately?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the designer.vb file and then it regenerated properly. I don't know how you are supposed to trigger a regeneration, but it seems like this shouldn't have persisted nearly as long as it did (after several builds, etc.), but it generated the correct code this time.